# eclipse invalid name on this platform

Tags: java, windows

I am not able to create a class with name 'Aux' getting error message invalid name on this platform.

```
OS: windows 8
Eclispe : Version: Juno Service Release 2 Build id: 20130225-0426
```

why is this restriction. Is Aux a system folder ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some of the names like:

> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9

are reserved name in Windows and cannot be used. So that's why you are getting that error. You need to change the name.

[Refer this MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information. Refer "Naming Conventions" section specifically to know the valid/invaild names of Windows platform.

Comment: is there any link where i can get all these reserved words

Comment: @upog, I posted the link to MSDN

Comment: yes, i tried already to accept it, but i have to wait for another 5 mins :)